# ORA 31001 XML parsing failed

Tags: xml, oracle, plsql

```
select
    XMLELEMENT("BUSINESENTITIES",
    XMLAGG(
         XMLELEMENT("BUSINESSENTITY",
                         XMLELEMENT("ENTITYTYPE",ENTITY_TYPE),
                         XMLELEMENT("ACCREDITATIONNUMBER",ACCREDITATIONNUMBER),
                         XMLELEMENT("SITENUMBER",SITENUMBER),
                         XMLELEMENT("DEPTNUMBER",DEPTNUMBER),
                         XMLELEMENT("NAME",NAME)
         ) ) )   result
    from tmp
```

When I am trying to xmlagg it throwing this error.
Can someone help me in this. is there any other way of doing this

I check codepage. it this  WE8MSWIN1252  ( `SELECT value$ FROM sys.props$ WHERE name = 'NLS_CHARACTERSET'` )

[image]

Comment: I don't see any issue with syntax...I ran it here 
https://livesql.oracle.com/apex/f?p=590:1:114824718401481:::::

Answer (score 0):

You table seems to have characters outside ASCII, I also get strange result with this simple test:

```
SELECT XMLELEMENT("ENTITYTYPE", 'ö') FROM dual;
```

```
<ENTITYTYPE>Ã¶</ENTITYTYPE>
```

I managed to get a proper output with this one, maybe it also helps in your query.

```
SELECT XMLELEMENT("ENTITYTYPE", 'ö').getclobval() FROM dual;
```

```
<ENTITYTYPE>ö</ENTITYTYPE>
```